# How to copy files from Linux partition to windows partition (dual boot)?

Tags: dual-boot, windows

I have tried copying to mounted windows system, but error is such

```
cp /home/siim/aeg /run/media/siim/96A09DB9A09DA073
cp: cannot create regular file '/run/media/siim/96A09DB9A09DA073/aeg': Read-only file system
```

Comment: Is the partition mounted as read-only?  Add the output of `mount | grep /run/media` to your question.

Comment: I tried mount | grep /run/media. It doesn't give any output.

Comment: I think it's read-only problem. Question itself went outdated, I got the file to windows thru internet. 
But I think it's a interesting what needs an answer, so other could search it on the internet

Comment: OK. It looks like we need the output of just `mount` on its own. The `grep` bit was supposed to filter it down to file systems you’ve mounted, but this suggests there weren’t any?

Comment: just same what fought, what you wanted. I went thru grep tutorial online, because it's long time passed,  I used it back in school. I'll try mounting it. Great thanks.

Comment: I got the sda2 mounted. The problem seemed to be that partition has errors on it, and that is why it is mounted as read only. So I need to repair them using chkdsk in windows. 
i quess it sums it up.